# How to use Span in F# interactive?

Tags: f#, .net-core, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I try to add reference to `System.Memory` by

```
#r "C:/Program Files/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.5/System.Memory.dll"
```

But F# interactive still says `The value or constructor 'Span' is not defined`. And When I try to use open `System.Memory` it says `The namespace 'Memory' is not defined`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure the DLL is for the right target?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I am not sure about how to check it. The only extra info I can give is that if I run the program in a .fs file it runs. It made me think I have the correct dll but not sure about it's path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to `open System.Memory` but you do need to `open System`. You might also want to nuget System.Memory into a .NET framework application first, and then reference it. I wonder though how FSI will interact with `Span<T>`.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"C:\Users\username\Documents\Source\ConsoleApplication1\packages\System.Memory.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll"
#r "System.Runtime.dll"
#endif


open System
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<IsByRefLike; Struct>]
type S(count1: Span<int>, count2: Span<int>) =
    member x.Count1 = count1
    member x.Count2 = count2
```

Comment: **You might also want to nuget System.Memory into a .NET framework application first, and then reference it** I don't get this par. Can't I directly use that assembly?

Comment: @ozgur I assume your use case is from FSI. FSI is not on .netcore yet, hence you might or might not have issues with a System.Memory dll from netcoreapp. First try your original approach, but open System, then use Span. If that doesn't work for you pull down System.Memory and reference that. Netstandard 2.0 should cover .NET4.7.X and above. I use this trick often when testing a netcoreapp in FSI. But be aware that FSI is using a lot of reflection (I think), and might barf on reflecting on byref types. So to sum it up, you do need to #r System.Memory.dll, but you need to open System.